# Custom marshaling in JSON/BSON of nested fields in a struct

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a struct let's call it `Foo` which comes from an external package. I do not have control over that package.

This struct `Foo` as a very nested field. Let's call it `Bar`. Let's say nested of 3 levels. This field in in `[]byte` and I have my custom Marshaler to get concrete fields from it.

I want to store `Foo` in MongoDB making sure that the fields of `Bar` are stored not in `[]byte`.

What is the correct approach?

I know that the mongo go driver has a package `bson` with all Marshal/Unmarshal functions that if implemented can help but I do not have control over the struct `Foo`.

I was thinking to create my own `Foo` struct and then nest the original `Foo` something like

```golang
type MyOwnFoo struct {
  Foo
}
```

Is it the only way or there are other better and most idiomatic ways?